# Get Values of json into a sting using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I need to convert json values into a string so I can use copy to clipboard later.

This is an example of my json

```
{"name":"my name","class":"A","group":"my group","source":"internal"}
```

The sting should be in this format:

my name A my group internal

Thanks

Comment: `Object.values(obj).join(' ')`

Comment: it's json object you just need hold this json in vairable in call according to your requirment like  var data = {"name":"my name","class":"A","group":"my group","source":"internal"};    console.log(data.name+ ' '+data.class +' '+data.group+' '+data.source)

Comment: If it's JSON, you'll need to call `JSON.parse()` first to turn it into an Object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const object = {name:"my name",class:"A",group:"my group",source:"internal"};    
const result = object.name + ‘ ‘ + object.class + ‘ ‘ + object.group + ‘ ‘ + object.source;
```

If your json is a string then it needs to be parsed first by replacing the first line with the following:

```
const jsonString = ‘{"name":"my name","class":"A","group":"my group","source":"internal"}’;
const object = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```